# No permission to WRITE on SD Card

Tags: android, permissions, manifest, android-sdcard, save-image

I am desperatly looking for a mistake in my code and would really appreciate if sb could help me with that.
I am trying to save an Image to the SD Card of my Samsung Galaxy Tab s2
but no matter what code I use, I do not seem to be able to make any changes on the SD Card.

This code passage below demonstrates that despite the changes in the manifest, I have no permission to write data on the SD card.

Is there anyone who had the same problem or knows what is going on here?

(android:minSdkVersion="19"; android:targetSdkVersion="25")

CODE:

```
    File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath() + "/SaveImage");

    MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bmp ,"Image.jpg", "IMAGE");
```

MANIFEST:

```
<manifest

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.ma.singhalja.saveimage">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MEDIA_CONTENT_CONTROL"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
```

LOG:

```
03-28 01:16:54.647 14292-14292/com.ma.singhalja.saveimage E/MediaStore: Failed to insert image
                                                                    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=14292, uid=10141 requires android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
                                                                        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
```

Comment: did you add Runtime permission?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to handle runtime permission for this,Take a look in this steps

Copy this Class:

```
    public class PermissionHandler {


// Run Time Permission List
        private static final String MNC = "MNC";

        // Calendar group.
        public static final String READ_CALENDAR = Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR;
        public static final String WRITE_CALENDAR = Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR;

        // Camera group.
        public static final String CAMERA = Manifest.permission.CAMERA;

        // Contacts group.
        public static final String READ_CONTACTS = Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS;
        public static final String WRITE_CONTACTS = Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS;


        // Location group.
        public static final String ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
        public static final String ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;

        // Microphone group.
        public static final String RECORD_AUDIO = Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO;

        // Phone group.
        public static final String READ_PHONE_STATE = Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE;
        public static final String CALL_PHONE = Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE;
        public static final String READ_CALL_LOG = Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG;
        public static final String WRITE_CALL_LOG = Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG;
        public static final String ADD_VOICEMAIL = Manifest.permission.ADD_VOICEMAIL;
        public static final String USE_SIP = Manifest.permission.USE_SIP;
        public static final String PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS = Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS;

        // Sensors group.
        public static final String BODY_SENSORS = Manifest.permission.BODY_SENSORS;
        public static final String USE_FINGERPRINT = Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT;

        // SMS group.
        public static final String SEND_SMS = Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS;
        public static final String RECEIVE_SMS = Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS;
        public static final String READ_SMS = Manifest.permission.READ_SMS;
        public static final String RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH = Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH;
        public static final String RECEIVE_MMS = Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_MMS;
        public static final String READ_CELL_BROADCASTS = "android.permission.READ_CELL_BROADCASTS";

        // Bookmarks group.
        public static final String READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS = "com.android.browser.permission.READ_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS";
        public static final String WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS = "com.android.browser.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS";


        public static boolean isPermissionGranted(Activity mContext, String Permission, String Text, int PermissionCode) {

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                reqPermission(mContext, Text, PermissionCode, Permission);
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }


        public static void reqPermission(Activity mContext, String Text, int PermissionCode, String Permission) {
            if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(mContext, Permission)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mContext, new String[]{Permission}, PermissionCode);
            } else {
                openAlertDialog(mContext, Text);
            }
        }

        public static void openAlertDialog(final Context mContext, String Text) {

            new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
                    .setTitle("Permission")
                    .setMessage(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name) + " needs to access " + Text + " Permission for using this features from Setting >> Permissions.")
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // Your code
                            String packageName = "you.App.Id";
                            try {
                                //Open the specific App Info page:
                                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
                                mContext.startActivity(intent);

                            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                                //e.printStackTrace();
                                //Open the generic Apps page:
                                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS);
                                mContext.startActivity(intent);

                            }

                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // do nothing
                        }
                    })
                    .show();


        }

    }
```

Before you save image you need to check this

```
if (PermissionHandler.isPermissionGranted((Activity) mContext, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, "External Storage", 1000)) {
                        // Save your Image code
                    }
```

Thats it.Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Add runtime permission for access

```
Add library:
compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.2.1'

private String[] galleryPermissions = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, galleryPermissions)) {
        pickImageFromGallery();
    } else {
        EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, "Access for storage",
                101, galleryPermissions);
    }
```